# how to convert ppt slide to png using apache POI in android?

Tags: android

I want to convert each slide of a ppt file into corresponding png file using Apachi POI or any other mechanism.
Any good suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I am facing some issue by using apachi poi in android. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27222997/1584121 . can you help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I am working on the same Application. Converting into images is a tedious process where u need to make changes in the entire POI API especially in draw function.So the better option is you can change it into web or html view.

Comment: I am facing some issue by using apachi poi in android. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27222997/1584121 . can you help on this?