# Android - convert doc, docx pages and xls, xlsx sheets to html using apache POI

Tags: android, excel, apache-poi, doc, viewer

I am developing an android application. In which I want to show the doc, docx, xlx, xlsx files in my application.

After searched in google, I came to know that the apachi POI will convert these files into html. So that I have added the **"poi-3.8-20120326.jar"** into the libs folder and try to build the app. But I did face some dalvik build issue.

So, I searched about this issue and found that the POI jar is supporting for java apps not fully supported for android.

I got some opensource for converting ppt, pptx files.
https://github.com/qhm123/POI-Android

In these source code, they have downloaded the apache poi source code and added the source in the app and used it to convert the ppt, pptx files.

So I have used the following code for doc, docx pages to html.

```
WordToHtmlConverter.main(new String[]{"/sdcard/office/sample.doc", "/sdcard/office/sample.html"});
```

For this I have added the "org.apache.poi.hwpf" package in my app project. But I got the same dalvik build issue what I mentioned above. So I couldn't build the app.

So how can I do this using apache POI?

**Dalvik Error:**

```
[2014-12-01 13:55:27 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:27 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:27 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:27 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:27 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$5) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:27 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$6) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:27 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$7) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:28 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.Main$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:28 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.MyTableModel$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:29 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.lf5.util.LogFileParser$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:29 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LF5SwingUtils$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:29 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:29 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:29 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:29 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogFactor5ErrorDialog$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:29 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogFactor5InputDialog$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:29 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogFactor5InputDialog$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:29 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogFactor5InputDialog$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:29 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryExplorerModel$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:29 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryExplorerTree$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:29 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNodeEditor$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:30 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:38 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:38 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:38 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:38 - POI-operations] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-01 13:55:50 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2014-12-01 13:55:50 - POI-operations] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

Comment: Please, could you attach the Dalvik error message?

Comment: @kameny : I have updated the Dalvik error in the question.