# Android - microsoft office viewer in my app

Tags: android, sdk, ms-office, viewer

**What I have / tried:**

I am developing an android application. In which I have to add the viewer for the microsoft office documents(**doc, docx, ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx**) to the users. So I have searched in the internet. I got some reference about the apachi POI and doc4j for android.

So I tried to implement that inside my app. But I got lot of issues and also not getting any API references for that. So I have posted the question in the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222997/android-convert-doc-docx-pages-and-xls-xlsx-sheets-to-html-using-apache-poi). But I didn't get any solutions for that.

So I am deciding to add any other third party office viewer SDKs inside my app to view the microsoft-office documents.

I searched in the internet and I got the following third party document viewers.

[directoffice-mobile-sdk](http://www.csr.com/products/directoffice-mobile-sdk)

[aspose](http://www.aspose.com/android/total-component.aspx)

**What I want:**
What are the other third party office document viewer SDKs are available for android? and what is the best one to implement inside my app? So anybody give some suggestions on this?

Comment: Hi, Did u get the solution? My requirement is same!!

Comment: No. I didn't get any solution for this yet.

Comment: Did u implement any third party library (paid or not paid) in ur app?

Comment: Hi, did you got any solution for this ?

Comment: Did you get any solution or reference?

Comment: hi any update on this?

Comment: Hi, any updates?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's about 2 years since the question, but people are still asking if there is a solution.

The answer might be more obvious that you think - use the Microsoft Graph SDK:
http://dev.office.com/android

There are, of course, the equivalent iOS SDKs as well:
http://dev.office.com/ios

Although the SDKs aren't as obvious as "open this Word file", they do allow you to gain access to the Office 365 functionality from within your own apps.

I hope this helps someone...

Comment: This is online only. Is there anything similar for offline/local files?

Comment: Not for the MS solution, and I think that Google's Drive SDK has the same issue, but I've not played with it properly yet...