# I am trying to output a .docx file in TextView and it displays it for me, how can I fix it?

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpvqI.png)

I am new to Android, and I am trying to output the .docx and .doc file to TextView with the click of a button, it does not display my file correctly, how can I fix this? txt format is displayed as it should!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv_output;
    Button b_load;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE=10000;
    private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE=42;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE);}
        tv_output=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_output);
        b_load=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b_load);
        b_load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             performFileSearch();
            }
        });
    }
    //read content of the file
    private String readText(String input){
        File file=new File(input);
        StringBuilder text=new StringBuilder();
        try{
           BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
           String line;
           while((line= br.readLine())!=null){
               text.append(line);
               text.append("\n");

            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
    //select file from storage
    private void performFileSearch(){
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        startActivityForResult(intent,READ_REQUEST_CODE);}
    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(data!=null){Uri uri =data.getData();
                String path=uri.getPath();
                path=path.substring(path.indexOf(":")+1);
                Toast.makeText(this,""+path,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tv_output.setText(readText(path));}}}
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
 {if(requestCode==PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE){
            if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            else{Toast.makeText(this,"Permission not granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.docx` files are no `.txt` files. They are a special file format and cannot be shown as plain text. You could search a library to do that for you. But there seems like there is not much available for that problem, like it is also being [questionned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243423/android-microsoft-office-viewer-in-my-app).